# Http get 404 Not Found for URL: null

Tags: angular, angular2-services

i have tried sample application like Tour of heroes.

am trying to convert service cal to http get(InMemoryDbService) like below

**hero.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule, Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import {Hero} from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes'; 

    constructor(private http : Http) { }

    // working code
    //getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    //    return Promise.resolve(HEROS);
    //}

    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        debugger;
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl).toPromise().then(responce => responce.json().data as Hero[]).catch(this.handleError);

    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**in-memory-data.service.ts**

```
    import {InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

    export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let heroes = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Bala' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 5, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 6, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 7, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 8, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 9, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 10, name: 'Thulasi' },
            { id: 11, name: 'Thulasi' }
        ];
        return heroes;
    }
}
```

throws below errors:

```
hero-service.ts:25 An error occurred Response_body: Object
    headers: Header
    sok: false
    status: 404
    statusText: "Not Found"
    type: null
    url: null
    __proto__: Body
HeroService.handleError @ hero-service.ts:25
    ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232
    onInvoke @ core.umd.js:5975
    ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231
    Zone.run @ zone.js:114
    (anonymous function) @ zone.js:502
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265
    onInvokeTask @ core.umd.js:5966
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
    drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
    ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
    core.umd.js:2837 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null
```

Comment: The URL you're accessing doesn't seem to exist. Have you checked the browser devtools for error messages or details what exact URL was used for the request and if this URL is valid?

Comment: Your URL is `null` it seems (according to the error message). can you debug und check if this is really the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I see is, your `createDb()` doesn't look like the original..

It returns an object within the "collections" ..

`return {heroes};`

I guess that lib needs this object to build those URLs..

Docs: https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Hero-Tour: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#appendix-tour-of-heroes-in-memory-server

Comment: what does the {} syntax mean around the heroes object in this case (im new to typescript)?  thank you for your comment. I was trying to return the heroes object as well

Comment: `return {heroes};` will result in `return {heroes: heroes};`. an object with a property named `heroes`.